# Откуда берется странная линия в бэкграунде?

Tags: css

Здравствуйте! У меня есть вот такой http://spravka-azov.ru/paral/index.html бэкграунд, состоящий из повторяющейся картинки. Я не пойму, откуда берется эта странная линия в бэкграунде, на 420 пикс по высоте? Пожалуйста, объясните мне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это из-за стиля

```
    .pxs_container{...
      border-top:7px solid #333;
      border-bottom:7px solid #333;
...}
```

Comment: убрал оба бордера - все то же

Comment: кажется понял, это из-за картинки, нужна бесшовная текстура

Comment: врятли, у меня все норм и с обычной картинкой, когда убрал бордеры

Comment: Уже не суть важно, все равно бгкартинка была тестовая, в новых эффекта не видно. В любом случае, спасибо, общение само по себе заставляет думать:)